# How to get previous EndTime to calculate in new rows?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have below formatted table data values. I would like to get last operation completed status start time and end time duration need to show in next ready operation.

E.g: Original table format:

```
     Sno    Operation      Status               StartTime               EndTime    
    ------ -----------  -----------------     ---------------------  ---------------
    1        OP10       Complete              2017-03-01 07:00:00    2017-03-01 07:10:00
    1        OP20       Complete              2017-03-01 07:10:00    2017-03-01 07:30:00
    1        OP30       Ready                      Null                    Null
    2        OP10       Complete              2017-03-01 08:00:00    2017-03-01 08:10:00
    2        OP20       Ready                      Null                    Null 
    3        OP10       Complete              2017-03-01 09:00:00    2017-03-01 09:10:00
    3        OP20       Complete              2017-03-01 10:00:00    2017-03-01 10:10:00
    3        OP30       Ready                 2017-03-01 10:00:00    2017-03-01 10:10:00
```

I need output like this:

```
  Sno     Operation     Status          TotalDurationCountInMins     
------  ------------  ------------  ---------------------------------
    1        OP30       Ready                      20     
    2        OP20       Ready                      10
    3        OP30       Ready                      10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery to get the last operation complete times.

**Note:** If your Operation column contains data that can't be sorted (like 'start', 'middle', 'end') this query will produce **wrong** results.

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    Sno int,
    Operation char(5),
    [Status] varchar(8),
    StartTime datetime, 
    EndTime datetime
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 'OP10', 'Complete', '2017-03-01 07:00:00', '2017-03-01 07:10:00'),
(1, 'OP20', 'Complete', '2017-03-01 07:10:00', '2017-03-01 07:30:00'),
(1, 'OP30', 'Ready', Null, Null),
(2, 'OP10', 'Complete', '2017-03-01 08:00:00', '2017-03-01 08:10:00'),
(2, 'OP20', 'Ready', Null, Null),
(3, 'OP10', 'Complete', '2017-03-01 09:00:00', '2017-03-01 09:10:00'),
(3, 'OP20', 'Complete', '2017-03-01 10:00:00', '2017-03-01 10:10:00'),
(3, 'OP30', 'Ready', '2017-03-01 10:00:00', '2017-03-01 10:10:00')
```

The Query:

```
SELECT  Sno, 
        Operation, 
        [Status],
        (SELECT TOP 1 DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartTime, EndTime)
         FROM @T t2
         WHERE t2.Sno = t1.Sno
         AND t2.Operation < t1.Operation
         AND t2.[Status] = 'Complete'
         ORDER BY StartTime DESC
         ) AS TotalDurationCountInMins
FROM @T t1
WHERE [Status] = 'Ready'
```

Results:

```
Sno     Operation   Status  TotalDurationCountInMins
1       OP30        Ready   20
2       OP20        Ready   10
3       OP30        Ready   10
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/IAQF67298)